# Conditionally change background image based on user selection, using Django?

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, multiple-choice

Hi this seems to be a simple issue but I'm new to programming, Python & Django. I'm creating a multiple choice quiz using Python which has 10 questions, and can be viewed as a web-application by the user - similar to the Django polls app.

Based on the answer the user selects for each question, I want the background image to change conditionally. 2 different background images - when the answer is wrong vs right, in the results webpage.

At the moment, I am able to load the static image but not conditionally based on the user's choice selection. Looks like it should be an if/else html tag?

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

templates > quizzes > results.html:

```
{% if selected_choice  == 'Apple' %}
    <h1 style= 'color:white;' class="correct">Correct! Good job.</h1>
    {% load static %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'quizzes/style2.css' %}">
{% else %}
    <h1 style= 'color:white;' class="wrong">Wrong!! The correct answer is Apple.</h1>
    {% load static %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'quizzes/style3.css' %}">    
{% endif %}
```

Comment: why are you loading whole different stylesheets depending on the user's answer? (This is wrong for several reasons, one being that we are clearly inside the document's `<body>` while `<link>` elements should only be in the `<head>`.) If you're trying to change a particular element's background image, you can give that element a different class depending on the result of the `{% if ... %}` and use just one CSS stylesheet to ensure each class gives the correct image.

Comment: Thanks for the help Robin, much appreciated.